# Use a path at a SQLite DB and use it to get an Image

Tags: java, android, sql

I have created a SQLITE DB to use their values at an Android app:

```
mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("MINERALG", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    mydatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MINERALS");
    mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MINERALS(Name TEXT, Type TEXT, Subtype TEXT, Formula TEXT, Path TEXT);");
    mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO MINERALS VALUES('calcite','Non Silicate','Carbonates','CaCO3','app/src/main/res/drawable/calcite.jpg');");
```

Using intent.putExtra("path",[String of the path]) and intent.getStringExtra("path"), I have passed the path as a String and I have it at another activity.

The problem is I don´t find the way to show the image at the 2nd activity.  I have the file calcite.jpg at the drawable folder of the project. I try:

```
imgM = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
String imgMine = intent.getStringExtra("path");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgMine);
imgM.setImageURI(uri);
```

It don´t throws error message, but it don´t show the image as I try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access files in the res directory that way... 
Better move the images in the assets directory, store the path in the db and load them by:

```
String imgMine = intent.getStringExtra("path");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/" + imgMine);
```

Comment: I have moved the picture to two assets folder (generated and intermediate). Then I do Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/" + imgMine); imgM.setImageURI(uri); I then save at DB: 'app/build/generated/assets/calcite.jpg' , but I should be still doing something bad. Sorry, I am new at pl. It should be something quite simply.

Comment: Don't store the path as "app/build/generated/assets/calcite.jpg".
It has to be just "calcite.jpg" since the file is located in the assets root. :)

Comment: I don´t get it. I pass correctly calcite.jpg (I tested it at an EditText). The ImageView has nothing special. I I make a .background(Color.red) it turns red. I leave the files tree in another comment and the XML code

Comment: I finaly solved it using drawable folder.                                                 int id=getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.manu.minerals:  drawable/"+ imageMine, null, null); //where imageMine="calcite" (without file extension).  imgM.setImageResource(id);                                                                           Thanks for guiding me to use just the name of the file at the SQL DB.